# Running ForceAtlas2 from a set position in Sigma.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, networking, graph, sigma.js

I am trying to render a complex network using the React-Sigma wrapper. I know the base structure of this network to be many nodes of degree one and some of a very high degree. To this end, I have preformatted my graph data with x and y coordinates that represent an approximate layout, with degree one nodes clustered around the nodes they are connected to. I then want to run the ForceAtlas2 simulation *from this point*. However, when I try to do this, the simulation appears to just randomise and change the initial positions of the nodes to be in the centre, as seen in this gif:

[image: Node animation]

Is there any way to stop this from happening and run the simulation from the initial positions? My code is below:

```
const App = () => {
    const myGraph = getExampleGraph();
    return (
        <Sigma
            graph={myGraph}
            renderer="webgl"
            settings={{
                clone: false,
                batchEdgesDrawing: true,
            }}
            style={{
                height: "100vh"
            }}
        >
            <ForceAtlas2
                iterationsPerRender={1}
                barnesHutOptimize
                barnesHutTheta={1}
                timeout={50000}
                worker
            />
        </Sigma>
    )
}
```

Code to get a random example graph like the one I described:

```
export const getRandomInt = (max: number) => Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));

export const getRandomPosition = () => ({
    x: Math.random(),
    y: Math.random()
});

export const randomisePosition = (position) => ({
    x: position.x + (Math.random() - .5)/10,
    y: position.y + (Math.random() - .5)/10
});


export const getExampleGraph = () => {

    const positions: any = {
        "1": getRandomPosition(),
        "2": getRandomPosition(),
        "3": getRandomPosition()
    };
    const highDegNodes = [
        { id: "1", size: 20, label: "1", ...positions["1"]},
        { id: "2", size: 20, label: "2", ...positions["2"] },
        { id: "3", size: 20, label: "3", ...positions["3"] }
    ];
    const nodes = Object.assign([], highDegNodes);
    const edges = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < 50; i += 1) {
        const id = (i + 4) + '';
        const node = { id, size: 1, label: id, x: 0, y: 0 };

        const target = (getRandomInt(3) + 1) + '';
        edges.push({
            id: `${id}:${target}:${i}`,
            source: id,
            target,
        });

        const nodePos = randomisePosition(positions[target]);
        node.x = nodePos.x;
        node.y = nodePos.y;
        nodes.push(node);

        if (Math.random() < .1) {
            const target2 = (getRandomInt(3) + 1) + '';
            edges.push({
                id: `${id}:${target2}:${i}:2`,
                source: id,
                target: target2,
            });
        }
    }

    return {
        nodes,
        edges
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem there is with implementation of ForceAtlas2 used in Sigma.js. It expects a higher scale of positions and is highly unstable at scale under 1.

The easiest to stabilize is you can multiply your positions by 100:

```js
const getRandomPosition = () => ({
    x: Math.random()*100,
    y: Math.random()*100
});

const randomisePosition = (position) => ({
    x: position.x + (Math.random() - .5)*10,
    y: position.y + (Math.random() - .5)*10
});
```

you could also apply slowDown={10} to forceAtlas to make it softer and remove batchEdgesDrawing if your graph is not too big:

```
        <Sigma
            graph={myGraph}
            renderer="webgl"
            settings={{
                clone: false,
            }}
            style={{
                height: "100vh"
            }}
        >
          <ForceAtlas2
               iterationsPerRender={1}
               barnesHutOptimize
               barnesHutTheta={1}
               slowDown={10}
               timeout={2000}
               worker
          />
        </Sigma>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! The nodes don't like staying in the correct position but it's certainly an improvement, thanks.